# Почему с selenium chromedriver + python вылетает браузер?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Моя программа запускает функцию driver.get("https://..."), браузер запускается и через пару секунд закрывается, хотя я не давал команду на закрытие. Что не так?
Если что, я проверил, версия chromedriver совместима с моим Chrome.

Код:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  
chrome_options = Options() 
chrome_options.add_argument("By")  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/chromedriver.exe", 
options=chrome_options) 
driver.get("https://...") 
login = driver.find_element("name", "login") 
login.send_keys("...") 
password = driver.find_element("name", "password")                             
password.send_keys("....") 
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) 
assert "No results found." not in driver
```

Comment: А у Вас `/chromedriver.exe` точно в корне находится или оно все таки в папке с проектом `./chromedriver.exe` должно быть?

Comment: `assert "No results found." not in driver` не помню точно уже, давно с селениумом не работал, но что-то мне подсказывает что в переменной `driver` не будет текстовой информации

Comment: Так же вызывает смущение вот эта запись. `chrome_options.add_argument("By")`. Могу конечно заблуждаться, но не припомню у chromdriver аргумента  `By`. У селениума есть такой объект Но чтобы он так использовался...

Comment: @Namerek, аргумента By действительно нет, но эта штука всё равно ничего не меняет и код не зависит от этой строки. И да, chromedriver.exe лежит в корне.

Comment: `/` это корень в системах типа `Linux` файл имеет расширение `exe` говорящее о том, что это запускаем файл `Windows`... Внимание вопрос. У Вас операционка какая?

Comment: @Namerek, я уже сам разобрался. Оказывается, правильному исполнению кода как-то мешал импорт requests. Я его закомментировал, и браузер перестал самопроизвольно закрываться. А так у меня винда, но всё работает и с /.